# Cannot 'coerce' data type with 'Reader' as a field

Tags: haskell, coercion, newtype, coerce

I have the following Haskell code, that compiles perfectly:

```
import Control.Monad.Reader (Reader (..))
import Data.Coerce (Coercible, coerce)

data Flow i o = Flow (i -> o) (o -> i)

coerceFlow
    :: (Coercible i i', Coercible o o')
    => Flow i o
    -> Flow i' o'
coerceFlow = coerce
```

However, if I change the definition of the `Flow` type to the following:

```
data Flow i o = Flow (i -> Reader Int o) (o -> i)
```

I start seeing a weird error:

```
Coerce.hs:10:14: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘o’ with ‘o'’ arising from a use of ‘coerce’
      ‘o’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          coerceFlow :: forall i i' o o'.
                        (Coercible i i', Coercible o o') =>
                        Flow i o -> Flow i' o'
        at Coerce.hs:(6,1)-(9,17)
      ‘o'’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          coerceFlow :: forall i i' o o'.
                        (Coercible i i', Coercible o o') =>
                        Flow i o -> Flow i' o'
        at Coerce.hs:(6,1)-(9,17)
    • In the expression: coerce
      In an equation for ‘coerceFlow’: coerceFlow = coerce
    • Relevant bindings include
        coerceFlow :: Flow i o -> Flow i' o' (bound at Coerce.hs:10:1)
   |
10 | coerceFlow = coerce
   |              ^^^^^^
```

As I understand, my data type is no longer `Coercible` automatically. Is there a way to tell GHC that I can coerce values of type `Flow` automatically? I can `coerce` each field manually, but I would like to `coerce` the whole data type at once (this is required for `DerivingVia` to work).

I tried using the `RoleAnnotations` extension like this:

```
type role Flow representational representational
```

But I see an error:

```
Coerce.hs:6:1: error:
    • Role mismatch on variable o:
        Annotation says representational but role nominal is required
    • while checking a role annotation for ‘Flow’
  |
6 | type role Flow representational representational
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's investigate:

```
> :info Reader
type Reader r = ReaderT r Data.Functor.Identity.Identity :: * -> *
        -- Defined in `Control.Monad.Trans.Reader'
```

So, `Reader` is defined in terms of `ReaderT`.

```
> :info ReaderT
type role ReaderT representational representational nominal
newtype ReaderT r (m :: k -> *) (a :: k)
  = ReaderT {runReaderT :: r -> m a}
        -- Defined in `Control.Monad.Trans.Reader'
```

... and `ReaderT` is `nominal` on its third argument, causing `Reader` to be `nominal` in its second argument, and making your coercion fail. You can't subvert this using a role annotation for your `Flow` type, since that would cope with the previous role annotation of `ReaderT`.

Now, you might wonder why `ReaderT` has a `nominal` third argument. To understand that, consider its definition:

```
newtype ReaderT r m a = ReaderT (r -> m a)
```

What should be the role of `a`, above? Well, it depends. If `m :: * -> *` is `representational` on its argument, then `ReaderT` is such on `a`. The same holds for `nominal` and `phantom`. The "best" way to express the role here would be to use a role polymorphism like

```
type role forall r .
     ReaderT representational (representational :: (* with role r) -> *) r
```

where the role of the third argument depends on the second higher-kinded argument.

Alas, GHC does not support role polymorphism like the above one, so we get to use only the most restrictive role: `nominal`.

Comment: Ooh, this is actually rather interesting. Note that if you import `ReaderT` (the `newtype` constructor is the important part), you *do* get `coerce :: (Coercible i i', Coercible o o') => Reader i o -> Reader i' o'`. However, even with that imported, the OP's code doesn't work. it appears the coercion solver's ability to ignore roles on `newtype`s doesn't extend to `data`. I'm unsure if that's intended or an oversight or what.

Comment: @HTNW That's.. weird. I did not expect that `coerce` to type. It looks like GHC is unfolding the first `data` definition, but not the second one in the OP case.

Comment: I think [this proposal](https://github.com/ghc-proposals/ghc-proposals/pull/276) would actually make the OP's code work by allowing GHC to peer into `data` as well as `newtype` (again, as long as all the relevant constructors are visible). Not sure though.

Answer (score 4):

The issue, explained by @chi, is no longer an issue if you avoid using ReaderT and use a textbook `(->) r` monad:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
module Foo where
import Data.Coerce (Coercible, coerce)

newtype RT r o = RT { runR :: r -> o }
data Flow i o = Flow (i -> RT Int o) (o -> i)

coerceFlow
    :: (Coercible i i', Coercible o o')
    => Flow i o
    -> Flow i' o'
coerceFlow = coerce
```